# Named Buttons in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create a button in an Android layout with name `"="` and Eclipse says:

> It is not acceptable.

How can I create a button with name `"="` or `"1"` etc?

here is the buttons:
[image]

Here is xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:text="7" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="8" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="9" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="4" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:text="5" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="6" />

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:text="1" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:text="2" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:text="3" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:text="." />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:text="0" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button9"
    android:text="=" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="/" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:text="-" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
    android:text="+" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
     android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the source itself?

Comment: you are creating button using eclipse framework itself or using Java to create it.

Comment: I use Graphical Layout in eclipse Here is the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the name of the button with the text shown on the button. So please give your button the name "buttonEquals" (or the like), and just set its text (or label) to "=".

Comment: Thanks Bananeweizen but i want to build a calculator then i have to find a way.

Comment: No. Please read my answer again. Your comment shows you did not understand the difference between the name of the button object (which is just for you as developer) and the text of the button (which is what the user finally sees). You _cannot_ have a Java object with the name "=". You _can_ have Java objects with _properties_ having the value "=".

Comment: Thanks Bananeweizen for your help i get it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button mybtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.YOURBUTTONID);
mybtn.setText("=");
```